# If $a, b, c$ are integers with $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, then $a$ and $b$ cannot both be odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a, b, c$ are integers with $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, it's true that $a$ and $b$ cannot both be odd.

But how can we prove it

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer on. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can prove this by contradiction.

$\text{Let }\;\; a = 2m+1, b = 2n + 1 $

So, the LHS is:
$$
\begin{align}
a^2 + b^2 &= 4(m^2+n^2) + 4(m+n) + 2 \\\\ 
          &= 2\left( 2(m^2+n^2) + 2(m+n)+1 \right) \\\\
          &= 2\times\text{an odd number}
\end{align}
$$

This can not be a perfect square, as it doesn't have an even power of $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible squares $\mod 4$ are $1$ or $0$, corresponding to whether the original number is odd or even. If both $a$ and $b$ are odd, that means that $c^2 \equiv 1 + 1 \equiv 2\mod 4$, but this is impossible.